# Fitting two plots of different sizes in one in GnuPlot

Tags: gnuplot

I have already spent hours browsing google for an answer but unsuccesfully. I was trying to work out how to fit two plots in one using multiplot in gnuplot in such a proportion as is visualized on the graph below. I was altering sizes, ratios etc., but it never worked. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you've searched, but I'm surprised that you haven't come across `set size` and `set origin`. In the gnuplot console check `help size` and `help origin`. Check the following code:

**Code:**

```
### multiplot with custom proportions

mySplit = 0.7

set multiplot

    set origin 0,0
    set size   1, mySplit
    plot sin(x)

    set origin 0, mySplit
    set size   1, 1-mySplit
    set ytics 0.5
    plot cos(x)

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]